# Locate Syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

I'm trying to return all rows that contain a substring in mysql

and here is my code

```
SELECT        Last_Name, Midle_Name, First_Name, Phone_home
FROM            contact_info
LOCATE   (@prefixText, Last_Name)
```

but I'm getting an error.

please help me with the correct syntax for LOCATE in my case.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT Last_Name, Midle_Name, First_Name, Phone_home
FROM   contact_info
WHERE  LOCATE(@prefixText, Last_Name) != 0
```